# Wordpress site in subdomain > menü links not working

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have made a clone of a website (wordpress) and put it in a subfolder. Everything works fine, except that the links are not working. It always redirects me to the main folder of the website.

Here is the new website: http://www.4progress.eu/new/

Try the menu links or try to just copy this link here as an example (see how it redirects to the mail (old) page): http://www.4progress.eu/new/outdoor-training/

What could be the problem? Can someone help me here?

Comment: Did you set the project directory in the settings already?  https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question is are you familiar with .htaccess file if yes then rewrite URL rules for your new site which is in sub folder.
For quick solution go to setting-> permalinks  and select another type of permalink for example "plain" and you are good to go. 
hope i have cleared your point 
Thanks